# SQL Server 2008 - Grouping results into 5 minute intervals

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I currently have a SQL script that returns the results of data items that are processed into the database from imported files, however we are looking at getting a count of the number of items that come into the database broken into 5 minute intervals, for a defined day.

My existing script is as follows:

```
declare @date datetime
set @date = '2016-12-07 00:00:00.000

Select filename, IE.dateprocessingstarted
  from tdii_inboundprocessed IE 
  inner join consignmentpf cpf
      on ie.inboundfileprocessedid = cpf.inboundprocessedid
where 1=1 and (ie.dateprocessingstarted between `@date` and `dateadd(dd,1,@date)`
```

This returns the following:

FilenameDate      ProcessingStarted

GOOD813546 2016-12-07 00:02:00
GOOD813546 2016-12-07 00:02:00
GOOD813546 2016-12-07 00:02:00
GOOD813546 2016-12-07 00:02:00
GOOD813546 2016-12-07 00:02:00
GOOD813546 2016-12-07 00:02:00
GOOD813554 2016-12-07 00:08:00
GOOD813554 2016-12-07 00:08:00
GOOD813554 2016-12-07 00:08:00
GOOD813554 2016-12-07 00:08:00

What I'd like to see is:
datetime                numberoffiles
2016-12-07 00:05:00      6
2016-12-07 00:10:00      4

etc

the tdii_inboundprocessed table contains the details of files coming into the system, including the time we are interested in dateprocessingstarted) the consignmentpf table contains the details of items within a particular file and this is the number we are interested in getting a count of.

Thank you for any help

Comment: please show some sample data and expected result and explain along with it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  t.date ,
        COUNT(*)
FROM    ( SELECT    DATEADD(MINUTE,
                            ( ( DATEDIFF(MINUTE, @date,
                                         IE.dateprocessingstarted) / 5 ) * 5 )
                            + 5, @date) [date]
          FROM      @tdii_inboundprocessed IE
                    INNER JOIN consignmentpf cpf ON IE.inboundfileprocessedid = cpf.inboundprocessedid
          WHERE     1 = 1
                    AND ( IE.dateprocessingstarted BETWEEN @date
                                                   AND     DATEADD(dd, 1,
                                                              @date) )
        ) AS t
GROUP BY t.date;
```